# How to multiply function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I am quite new to JS technology and I try to figure out if it is possible to create the same function many times (for example in some loop). The main issue is that I create buttons and checkboxes in foreach loop. The problem is that I do not know how many elements will be in List lista and how many JS functions will I need to show div contents. So is there any way to solve this problem with code like below or should I try something else if so, could you please give me some advice how can I solve it?

I place part of my code below:

HTML code:

```
List<string> lista = ViewBag.Dane;
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
@foreach (var elem in lista){
<label><input id="machine" type="checkbox" value="A" onchange="changeA()"/>choose all </label>
<button id="buttonA" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDivsA()">@elem</button>
<div id="myDropdownA" class="dropdown-content">
<label><input id="machine" type="checkbox" value="A" onchange="change()"/>choose all </label>
<button id="buttonA" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDivsAa()">MachineB2</button>
<div id="myDropdownAa" class="dropdown-content">
<!-- div's content -->
</div></div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function changeA() {
if (document.getElementById('buttonA').disabled === true){
$('#buttonA').removeAttr('disabled');}
function showDivsA() {
if (document.getElementById('myDropdownA').style.display === "none") {
        document.getElementById('myDropdownA').style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('myDropdownA').style.display = "none";}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should use CSS instead.

Comment: You're looking for parameters.

Comment: You need to make a function reusable, not make copies of the function.

Comment: Indenting code properly is a great way to make it readable.

Comment: Make the same JS function handle all the rows in your list.  Rather than using IDs all over the place, determine the clicked element with `this` and then locate the other elements you want to work with in a relative manner (`$(this).parent.find('select')` for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a single function and pass parameters accordingly from HTML. For Example,

```
// call this function like changeA('buttonA') from HTML
function changeA(buttonIdStr) 
{
   if (document.getElementById(buttonIdStr).disabled === true)
   {
      $('#' + buttonIdStr).removeAttr('disabled');
   }
}

// call this function like showDivsA('myDropdownA') from HTML
function showDivsA(dropDownIdstr) 
{
   if (document.getElementById(dropDownIdstr).style.display === "none") 
   {
        document.getElementById(dropDownIdstr).style.display = "block";
   }
   else 
   {
        document.getElementById(dropDownIdstr).style.display = "none";
   }
}
```